# 3D pcolor/pclormesh plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, visualization

#### 1. My attempt

- 2-d numpy array represent some value of an area, showing like this:

http://i8.tietuku.com/90d045a6c2375474.png

And I want to plot the value in the Z-axis.

For example, If I want to plot the altitude of this area, using 3d pcolor plot, I can get a figure just like the real terrain.

#### 2. My result

For now, I can plot 3-d plot of this area using

*Code*

```
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d
fig,ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'),figsize = (12,8))
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy,value,rstride = 1,cstride = 1,\
            cmap=plt.cm.Spectral_r,linewidth = 0)
```

*Result*

http://i4.tietuku.com/b2e650d0d23d5756.png

Can some one offer some advice to plot 3-d based on each grid value (like a 3-d histogram)?

#### Update

A little question added here, how to change the xticks and yticks in 3-d axes?

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/bars3d_demo.html what you are looking for?